# Javacpp: Can't manage to add libfdk_aac to ffmpeg presets

Tags: java, maven, ffmpeg, javacv, javacpp

We're trying to recompile ffmpeg project using javacpp and with the `--enable-libfdk-aac` enabled, the build works, but we can't use libfdk_aac to decode an audio_stream.

We are calling : `avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("libfdk_aac")` and getting the following result:

`Exception: avcodec_find_decoder() error: Unsupported audio format or codec not found: 86018.`

We've modified the ccpbuild.sh in the ffmpeg directory in the following way:

1. Adding the instruction: `--enable-libfdk-aac`  in the ENABLE variable
2. Getting the dependency : `download https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac/tarball/master fdk-aac.tar.gz`
3. Unpacking it: `tar -xzvf ../fdk-aac.tar.gz`
4. Installing it:

   `cd ../mstorsjo-fdk-aac*
   autoreconf -fiv
   ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --disable-shared --with-pic
   make -j $MAKEJ
   make install`

I'm running all this on a macosx platform.

The process seems to be ok, and I can compile the project properly with maven, but then it does not work when I'm calling the codec "libfdk_aac".
I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or is there any other place where I need to register this codec ? (especially since this is an external library)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end there are not any issue with the javacpp presets for ffmpeg. The way we added libfdk in the preset (as I described it in my question post), was correct.

However in the FFmpegFrameGrabber class in Javacv, we were missing a method to "force" an audio codec when decoding the media. 
We've modified this class to add a setAudioCodecName method and this is now working properly.
We can then set libfdk_aac (or any other codec) to decode audio, or encode audio with it using the FFmpegFrameRecorder.